# Can I Use Java in the Terminal Without Installing It?

Tags: macos, java, jre

I want to know if there is a way to use commands that require Java (since I'm an Android developer), like the `./gradlew` command, without installing the JRE on macOS. Is it possible to do this

Comment: If you want to run a Java program then what do you expect to actually do the running?  Either you have a system-wide interpreter/jit or each program would have to either bundle an interpreter or be compiled down to native code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like Java portable and see if it works. If you are an Android developer, you should definitely have JDK (Java Development Kit) installed to build your apps.

When using Windows you can run .jar files using something like [jPortable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) together with [jPortable Launcher](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable_launcher) or wrap them using [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) and deploy as .exe files. I don't know about any tools like this for macOS, apart from using Automator with AppleScript to launch .jar. You can then save everything as a runnable macOS app. You still need Java for both AppleScript and Launch4J though.

Comment: Why the downvotes on both answers? They are perfectly fine and give you suggestions on how to solve your problems.

Answer (score -2):

It shouldn't be possible to run commands that depend on Java without something having JRE.

However, as an alternative you might be able to use a docker container that has Java, mount your volume to the docker container, and run commands.

- https://www.docker.com/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/java/ (Deprecated)
- https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

Something like this:

`` docker run -it -v `pwd`/project:/app java:latest /bin/bash ``

Or you can make your own Dockerfile with gradle and everything installed.